# Multidata and dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a dynamic form like this: https://s.bootsnipp.com/iframe/VVyP

I want to know how I can do to capture and process the data in PHP. I have to make some sums with the values that are placed in the fields and check that they are not blank.

Comment: You can use the input fields as array, e.g. `names[]` and in php you can loop through to the length.

Comment: I will test, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick intro to form processing in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Send the form to the server and process the data. The user can submit the form using a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

By default this will load whatever URL is specified in the form's action attribute:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
```

From your PHP script, you'll be able to access the form data through the $_POST array:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

An alternative to a full page load is using an AJAX request to submit the data.